# Karma error: Expected one matching request for criteria

Tags: angular, api, unit-testing, service, karma-jasmine

I have seen many posts on this error but most of them seem to be due to parameters. I am calling the GetAll API method and it should not have any parameters.

Below are my codes:

I have imported the required services and modules:

```
import {EmployeeService} from '../employee.service';
import { SalaryService } from '../salary.service';
import { TaxationService } from '../taxation.service';
import { HttpClientModule , HttpClient, HttpHandler} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpTestingController ,HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
```

In my describe, I have created the required service instance and injected them where required:

```
let httpClient: HttpClient;
let httpTestingMockController: HttpTestingController;
let employeeService: EmployeeService;
let salaryServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<SalaryService>;

beforeEach(async(() => {

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  providers: [EmployeeService, HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHandler],
  declarations: [ EmployeeComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();

httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
httpTestingMockController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
employeeService = TestBed.inject(EmployeeService);
salaryServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(SalaryService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SalaryService>;
}));

beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmployeeComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
httpTestingMockController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

employeeService = TestBed.inject(EmployeeService);
salaryServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(SalaryService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SalaryService>;
});


it('Should fetch a list of employees',() => {
const mockEmployeeData = [
{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","salary":10000.00,"dateJoined":
 "2020-08-30T12:59:03.4433333"}
 ];

employeeService.getAllEmployees().subscribe((result)=>{
  expect(result.length).toBe(1);
  console.warn(result.length);
  expect(result).toEqual(mockEmployeeData);
});

let req = httpTestingMockController.expectOne('https://localhost:44328/api/Employee');

expect(req.request.method).toBe("GET");
req.flush(mockEmployeeData);

});
```

Karma is returning the below error:
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://localhost:44328/api/Employee",
found none.

Have I missed out anything?

Comment: can you replace url and try with this one - `/api/Employee`?

Comment: @Buczkowski Unfortunately, it still does not work, it returns this error: Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: /api/Employee", found none.

Comment: can you share your code/ ts file?

Comment: @avdeveloper : can you share ur service file as well ? I'll try to run  on my local and see